# Bitwise operation - return highest bit that is on

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

If I have a flags enum as a member on a class, for example a Port class with a SupportedUsbProtocols enum that is set up as follows:

```
[Flags]
public enum USB_PROTOCOLS : uint
{
    Usb110 = 0x01,
    Usb200 = 0x02,
    Usb300 = 0x04,
}
```

How could I most efficiently return the highest value contained in SupportedUsbProtocols using a bitwise operator?

For example, my Port class has a SupportedUsbProtocols and say for a particular instance, the SupportedUsbProtocols = Usb110 | Usb200. I want to return Usb200 from a method that I will call HighestUsbProtocolSupported (or something like that).

Comment: Do you want to return the highest flag *defined in the enum*, or the highest flag *set in a particular value*?

Comment: Try looking at [this SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784058/finding-the-highest-set-flag-in-an-enum-value)

Comment: Be careful, you probably don't literally want what you're asking. `(USB_PROTOCOLS) 128` is a valid value for this enum, but do you really want the result to be `128`, or rather an error that you don't support that particular value?

Comment: Good point. I want to return the highest protocol supported by the port. As you can see I have mapped the USB_PROTOCOLS union returned by the WinAPI call to IOCTL_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFO_EX_V2 into a enum with the Flags. I am iterating the ports and looking for the highest USB protocol supported.